# Python: set keys from __init__ for a subclass or metaclass dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to python. I am still not sure the functional benefits for subclassing or metaclassing an existing type -- so feel free to elaborate on that if you wish.

My question goes to the function `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` in the following class:

```
class NewDict(<sub / meta class here>):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #(is this needed) super(NewDict, self).__init__(args, kwargs)

    self.a_specific_key = a_passed_variable
```

The goal is to call `NewDict` as follows:

```
nd = NewDict(a_passed_variable = a_value)
```

such that `nd["a_specific_key"]` returns `a_value`

Thus please address the how to define the init function such that this can be achieved.

For example:

```
def Test(dict):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__setitem__("key", kwargs["value"])

t = Test(a=5) 
## causes error
# goal is to be able to then call
t["key"]
--> 5
```

---

goal is to set up a dictionary template with a set number of keys and special methods related to those key, i.e. there will be many instances of the class and they should each have the same keys and methods. Hence why I want to set the keys from the init function.

Comment: You want to save "a_passed_variable" but the value you associate with it should be avaiable when you access "a_specific_key"? Could you elaborate what you want to use it for?

Comment: You could just subclass dict and that would work, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: @MSeifert it (mine) is a pretty stupid question. It is asking, more or less, that if I want to extend the dictionary class how can I set some key, value pairs from the init, rather then initializing the dictionary and then adding the key value pars after

Comment: @TankorSmash I think that is what I want to do, but I am not sure of the syntax for the init function

Comment: I think it should work by default: `dict(a=10, b=20)` creates this dictionary: `{'a': 10, 'b': 20}`

Comment: @MSeifert yes, but I want to set specific keys... so while that works, it doesn't necessarily make it clear the syntax I would use internally...

Comment: You are confusing attribute lookup (dotted, `.`) with indexing (bracketed, `[]`), the last og which is implemented via `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.

Comment: @jmd_dk the question is how to write __init__ function such that I can specify keys to be made in the new dictionary

Comment: Subclassing builtin-types is actually a very tricky buisness because you cannot access the underlying (C) attributes and you need to browse the source code to see if it uses `__new__` or `__init__` to actually create the type. It's possible, for example by using `self[key] = value` but I would strongly advice against it. Note that there might be interesting subclasses of dict already: `collections.defaultdict`, `collections.OrderedDict` and `collections.Counter`.

Comment: @MSeifert I dont understand why I wouldn't be able to access the underlying attributes... isn't that the purpose of subclassing, to inherit those attributes and methods?

Comment: If you're actually just looking to get an attribute by string, use `gettattr(instance, key, default_result)`. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve with this, maybe that'll help us understand what you want. Also, make sure your example code matches up exactly with what you want. The variable names don't match up.

Comment: @TankorSmash I added a bit more detail in the question, but honestly I don't know how I could be more clear. I want to make either a sub or meta class of a dictionary. I want to be able to call it with a few key values, and then explicitly in the init function set the keys of the dictionary to be those key words that were passed.

Comment: I still don't really understand. It sounds like you're looking for an interface where a class can only have certain members so check out `__slots__`, or maybe just a factory function that takes two args and spits back a plain old dict that contains the two values assigned to a preset pair of keys. Could you elaborate on the use case. I know you're new but there's a bunch of people here trying to help you, so its still not clear enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can be achieved with:

```
class NewDict(dict):
  _keys = ['my_key_1', 'my_key_2', ... ]
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for key in self._keys:
      if key in kwargs:
        self[key] = kwargs[key]
      else:
        self[key] = None
```

Comment: I appreciate that you self answered your question but I wonder why you did not even upvote my answer given that it probably contained a lot of the informations you needed to find your optimal solution?

Comment: @MSeifert at the time you posted your answer we did not seem to share a mutual understanding of what I wanted to achieve so I tinkered and pieced together a few other S.O. posts and posted this. I do not object to up-voting your answer but it did not answer my key concern, which was setting predesignated keys as to make a template for a dictionary